# How is the initialization of objects considered in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, attributes

In this class there is no attribute called "a" then how x.a is considered ? Similarly what is "x.a.b", "x.a.b.c", "x.a.b.c.d", "x.a.b.c.d.e" and how are they considered ?Is b is an attribute of x.a in the case of "x.a.b" and c is a attribute of x.a.b in the case of "x.a.b.c" ? Explain breifly !!! I am totally confused

```
class Node :
  def __init__(self, data = None, next = None) :
    self.data = data
    self.next = next
x = Node(50)
x.a = Node(40)
x.a.b = Node(30)
x.a.b.c = Node(20)
x.a.b.c.d = Node(10)
x.a.b.c.d.e = Node(5)
print(x.a.b.c.d.e.data)
```

Comment: Ok, but what do you think about `x = Node(50)`? Where does the `x` come from?

Comment: btw, I'm guessing from the name `Node` and that it has the `next` attribute that each of the nodes you are making should have their `next` attribute refer to the next `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that similar to the declaration of the first variable `x`, `x.a` is an implicit initialization of that variable. `x` doesn't exists until you initialize it, so does `x.a`.

So by initializing `x.a` you first need `x` to exists, that mean you cannot do something like

```py
class Node :
  def __init__(self, data = None, next = None) :
    self.data = data
    self.next = next
x = Node(50)
x.a = Node(40)
# Then try to create the chain until C without creating first b
x.a.b.c = Node(20)
```

If you test it out it will point

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", in <module>
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'b'
```

So in short. I think that even though the Node class has no attributes, the chain is just creating child nodes to the first variable.

```
x 
|_ Node() -> self, data, next
|_ a _
     |_ Node () -> self, data, next
     |_ b _
          |_ Node () -> self, data, next
          |_ c _ 
               |_ ...
```

Notice that as mentioned by quamrana, only `a` is directly attached to `x`.

Comment: In your original code posted, each instance of `Node` has a different extra attribute. That is: `x` has the `a` attribute, but `x` doesn't have any of the `b` .. `e` attributes. Similarly the `c` attribute of `b` has the `d` attribute, but not `x`, nor `a`, nor `b`, nor `e`.

Comment: But that is exactly what's representing with that declaration, isn't it? It's not assigning to the `next` attribute of `Node` it's only creating a new attribute of `x` that might have nothing to do with the `Node` class.

Comment: I'm just making sure that you, and all the future programmers who visit here, know that `x` is only given *one* extra attribute, because you state: `the chain is just creating child nodes to the first variable` by which I presume you meant that the chain is creating many nodes on `x` which is not true.

Comment: Oh sure, now I noticed that the way I expressed it was wrong, my apologies, do you think I should correct the text? Even in my "sketch" I tried to represent that `b` is only related to `a` and not directly to `x`.